# assertion failed: conflicting directory structures detected. Suspicious paths

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to read data from aws s3 where I am having error.

s3 bucket and paths for example as below:

```
s3://USA/Texas/Austin/valid
s3://USA/Texas/Austin/invalid 
s3://USA/Texas/Houston/valid
s3://USA/Texas/Houston/invalid 
s3://USA/Texas/Dallas/valid
s3://USA/Texas/Dallas/invalid 
s3://USA/Texas/San_Antonio/valid 
s3://USA/Texas/San_Antonio/invalid
```

when I try to read as

```
spark.read.parquet("s3://USA/Texas/Austin/valid")
```

or

```
spark.read.parquet("s3://USA/Texas/Austin/invalid")
```

or

```
spark.read.parquet("s3://USA/Texas/Austin")
```

it works just fine.

but when I try to read as

```
spark.read.parquet("s3://USA/Texas/*")
```

or

```
spark.read.parquet("s3://USA/Texas")
```

it throws an exception.

java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Conflicting directory structures detected. Suspicious paths:

If provided paths are partition directories, please set "basePath" in the options of the data source to specify the root directory of the table. If there are multiple root directories, please load them separately and then union them.

as per suggestion I can read them individually but I have more then 500 files, to read them individually and union them will be hectic.

is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Facing this same issue would you please let us know if you were able to fix it ? Or if you have a work around ?

Comment: @user1119283, I found to use use spark.read.parquet("s3://USA/Texas/*/*") This will let read all the paths though not the specific ones, but if you want you can add prefix. will read the ones which starts with Aus*/val*("s3://USA/Texas/Aus*/Val*") and so on. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I am using HDFS with Parquet but I ran into the same issue. For me, setting the basePath to a path level above anything you will be accessing in that query works.
Also, I believe the '*' is unnecessary, though I'm not sure of the behavior of S3 on this one.

eg.

```
spark.read.option("basePath", "s3://USA/Texas/").parquet("s3://USA/Texas/")
```

Perhaps this is off-base for your S3 scenario but will hopefully help someone else with HDFS getting the same error.

Answer (score -1):

If you can use `Hive`, then set two configurations

```
hive.input.dir.recursive=true
hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=true
```

and `create external table` on the root path. Then, the table should read all the subdirectories data in the table but the schema should be the same or it will get an error.